# Regular expressions : is it possible to take all words in a text in pairs?

Tags: regex, pcre

I am using PCRE to find all pairs of words in a phrase, eg. the phrase "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." should produce

```
The quick
quick brown
brown fox
fox jumped
jumped over
...
...
lazy dog
```

I am using the function FindAndConsume() which consumes both words and I am only getting half the results !

```
The quick
brown fox
jumped over
...
...
the lazy
```

So I am trying to find if there is a way to retrieve all the pairs of words.

Comment: I'm not a perl dev, but I can do this in PHP using the pattern `\b\w+?\W+\w+?\b`, but I believe this to be imperfect

Comment: @ExplosionPills: No, you can't. You will get the same result as OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions will not find overlapping matches. To do what you want to do, I suggest you first split your text into words, then use a normal loop to extract the items with their neighbours.

Alternately, you can put the second word in your regular expression in a lookahead, and capture it: [`(\w+)(?=\W+(\w+)\b)`](http://rubular.com/r/AiVWY7ZeVp) - but make sure you get the captures, not the matches (since the matches will still only include the first word).

Comment: Worked great. Thanks ! I also found another solution (not a great one) : after scanning as I did, remove the first word from the phrase and scan again - you get the other half of word pairs ;-)